# visual-studio-code go to symbol in json

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is vscode able to navigate to a symbol inside a JSON file or a javascript object? It would be helpful being able to jump to the keys on those structures. This can be enabled somehow or this just isn't implemented yet?

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you are going to get is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>@</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>which will list all the keys in your json file.  But it simply lists them in the order they appear, so you don't really gain a lot.  But as you ARROW down the list your json file and cursor will scroll to that entry so that is nice.

Comment: And this json viewer for firefox developer's edition looks interesting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/JSON_viewer